# Picture tapped from UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Good afternoon,

I have a UIPickerView that shows pictures of birds, different picture with different row selected in UIPickerView, now I want to tap the picture for more information about the bird, so I am thinking about a TextView that pops up when the picture is tapped. How would I implement that in my code? I am new to programming and any help is much appreciated. This is my code so far.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//Load up NSArray object
_fuglar = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Allt árið",@"Hrafn", @"Svartbakur",@"Silfurmáfur",@"Sílamáfur",@"Frá 20.ágúst til 15.mars",@"Grágæs",@"Heiðagæs",@"Frá 1.september til 15.mars",@"Fýll",@"Dílaskarfur",@"Toppskarfur",@"Helsingi",@"Stokkönd", @"Urtönd",@"Rauðhöfðaönd",@"Duggönd",@"Skúfönd",@"Hávella",@"Toppönd",@"Hvítmáfur",@"Hettumáfur",@"Rita",@"Frá 15.apríl til 14.júlí",@"Kjói(í og við friðlýst æðarvarp)",@"Frá 1.september til 25.apríl",@"Álka",@"Langvía",@"Stuttnefja",@"Teista",@"Lundi",@"-Breytilegt-",@"Rjúpa", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
#pragma mark - UIPickerView Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return _fuglar.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [_fuglar objectAtIndex:row];
}
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view

{
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 37)];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22];
if (row == 0 || row == 5 || row == 8 || row == 23 || row == 25 || row == 31) {
    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}else{
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
label.text = [_fuglar objectAtIndex:row];
return label;

if (row == 0) {
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"byssa2"];
} else {
    [_fuglar objectAtIndex:row];
}

}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
//Create UIImage objects



UIImage * byssa2Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"byssa2.jpg"];
UIImage * hrafnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hrafn.jpg"];
UIImage * svartbakurImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Svartbakur.jpg"];
UIImage * silfurmafurImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silfurmafur.jpg"];
UIImage * silamafurImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silamafur.jpg"];
UIImage * gragaesImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gragaes.jpg"];
UIImage * heidargaesImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Heidagaes.jpg"];
UIImage * fyllImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fyll.jpg"];
UIImage * toppskarfurImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dilaskarfur1.jpg"];
UIImage * dilaskarfurImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Toppskarfur.jpg"];
UIImage * helsingiImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Helsingi.jpg"];
UIImage * stokkondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Stokkond.jpg"];
UIImage * urtondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Urtond.jpg"];
UIImage * raudhofdaondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Raudhofdaond.jpg"];
UIImage * duggondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Duggond.jpg"];
UIImage * skufondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Skufond.jpg"];
UIImage * havellaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Havella.jpg"];
UIImage * toppondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Toppond.jpg"];
UIImage * hvitmafurImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hvitmafur.jpg"];
UIImage * hettumafurImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hettumafur.jpg"];
UIImage * ritaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rita.jpg"];
UIImage * alkaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Alka.jpg"];
UIImage * langviaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Langvia1.jpg"];
UIImage * stuttnefjaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Stuttnefja.jpg"];
UIImage * teistaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Teista1.jpg"];
UIImage * lundiImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lundi.jpg"];
UIImage * rjupaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rjupa1.jpg"];
UIImage * kjoiImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Kjoi.jpg"];



switch (row) {
        break;
    case 0:
        fuglarImage.image = byssa2Image;
        break;
    case 1:
        fuglarImage.image = hrafnImage;
        break;
    case 2:
        fuglarImage.image = svartbakurImage;
        break;
    case 3:
        fuglarImage.image = silfurmafurImage;
        break;
    case 4:
        fuglarImage.image = silamafurImage;
        break;
    case 6:
        fuglarImage.image = gragaesImage;
        break;
    case 7:
        fuglarImage.image = heidargaesImage;
        break;
    case 9:
        fuglarImage.image = fyllImage;
        break;
    case 10:
        fuglarImage.image = toppskarfurImage;
        break;
    case 11:
        fuglarImage.image = dilaskarfurImage;
        break;
    case 12:
        fuglarImage.image = helsingiImage;
        break;
    case 13:
        fuglarImage.image = stokkondImage;
        break;
    case 14:
        fuglarImage.image = urtondImage;
        break;
    case 15:
        fuglarImage.image = raudhofdaondImage;
        break;
    case 16:
        fuglarImage.image = duggondImage;
        break;
    case 17:
        fuglarImage.image = skufondImage;
        break;
    case 18:
        fuglarImage.image = havellaImage;
        break;
    case 19:
        fuglarImage.image = toppondImage;
        break;
    case 20:
        fuglarImage.image = hvitmafurImage;
        break;
    case 21:
        fuglarImage.image = hettumafurImage;
        break;
    case 22:
        fuglarImage.image = ritaImage;
        break;
    case 24:
        fuglarImage.image = kjoiImage;
        break;
    case 26:
        fuglarImage.image = alkaImage;
        break;
    case 27:
        fuglarImage.image = langviaImage;
        break;
    case 28:
        fuglarImage.image = stuttnefjaImage;
        break;
    case 29:
        fuglarImage.image = teistaImage;
        break;
    case 30:
        fuglarImage.image = lundiImage;
        break;
    case 32:
        fuglarImage.image = rjupaImage;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: add the Tap gesture for your imageview , on that action method open the view for detail describtion

Comment: Elaborate more about your requirement. Showing pictures in Picker View is not so good. 

You can show it in Collection View.

Comment: @BalajiRamakrishnan - r u seen the question on didSelectRow based on the selection he show the single image on imageview

Comment: Yeah !  Got it. Tap Gesture is the correct way to achieve his requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think what you need is a tap gesture on the picker itself, then when it's tapped you can decide what to do.. `pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`
 doesn't quite work the way you want it too right?

First off, wherever you create your picker / create your picker property

Something like this

```
-(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    if (!_pickerView) {

        _pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _pickerView.dataSource = self;
        _pickerView.delegate = self;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecogniser = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pickerTapped:)];
        tapGestureRecogniser.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        tapGestureRecogniser.delegate = self;
        [_pickerView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecogniser];
    }

    return _pickerView;
}
```

After this you need to add a little bit to make sure our tap gesture doesn't interfere with our pickers motion we need to add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` like so

```
@interface MYPickerViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

and also

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    return YES;
}
```

Now that's out of the way... we can handle tapping the picker. I've used `CELL_HEIGHT` to represent the height of your picker cells

```
-(void)pickerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecogniser
{
    NSLog(@"pickerTapped");

    CGPoint touchPoint = [tapGestureRecogniser locationInView:[self picker]];

        if (touchPoint.y < ([self picker].frame.size.height + CELL_HEIGHT)/2 && touchPoint.y > ([self picker].frame.size.height/2) - (CELL_HEIGHT/2)) // this makes sure the tap was actually on the selected cell
    {
        NSLog(@"Met tap criteria");

        NSInteger row = [self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
        [self presentInfoForRow:row];
    }
}
```

Finally the bit you asked for you want an alert to pop up

```
-(void)presentInfoForRow:(NSInteger)row
{

     NSString *title = @"";
     NSString *message = @"";

     // change your message depending on the row selected.
     // you used a switch above, but you'd be much better off creating a bird object, putting .image .title and .message fields in and sticking them in an array

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *doneAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"") style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

        }];

        [alertController addAction:doneAction];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply and code, much appreciated. Would this code pop up an alert when i tap on the picture or on the picker itself and where would I put the tap gesture recognizer, on the image or the picker? Do I put this code in my .m file exept UIGestureRecognizerDelegate that goes in .h file?

Comment: Hi Sleeperinn. It's really important that you try to interpret what each part is doing and try to fit it into your code. I know that's probably not what you want to hear but it's not often about dropping a segment of code into an m file and everything works. All the pieces are there though. It's hard to get an answer that can drop straight in when there's quite a lot to do to make it work. try to follow each step and apply it to your code. Be confident!

Comment: Hello Magoo and thanks for your help again,  I have put this code in and I can run it on simulator but nothing happens when i try to tap. Would it be possible for me to send you the .h and .m file via email and you could have a look at it and tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hi Sleeperinn, yes possibly, but it might not be necessary. I've added some NSLogs to the `-(void)pickerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecogniser` method.. can you add them and confirm you see *both* of them when you tap an image. If not that's where we'll need to start debugging.